# Matching rows without filtering (SQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got table with properties of some products:

```
table properties(
  prop_id int,
  product_id int
)
```

My question is: is it possible to select properties that match without filtering them from the result?  For example:

```
select property_id from properties WHERE property_id IN(1,3,5);
```

You get only rows that match 1,3,5.
I need all rows but with information of which rows matched my criteria.
I don't want to use 'UNION'.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have experience with mySQL, but assuming it supports a `case` statement (or something analagous), you could do this:

```
select
    prop_id,
    product_id,
    (case when prop_id in (1, 3, 5) then 1 else 0 end) as matches_criteria

from properties
```

Comment: +1 mySQL does support the case statement, but you need to end with 'end case'

Comment: Your syntax for MySQL looks fine to me. To the questioner: so with Adam's syntax, you get a new column -- if that column is a 1, then the row matched your your criteria.

Comment: Doh! @birdlips has it right. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html I make a terrible syntax checker. :-)

Comment: why the up votes here? the question isn't worded that well, but they were looking for a left join, not a case.

Comment: It's only CASE as a separate statement that needs END CASE.  The CASE inside a SELECT ends with END, not END CASE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement:

```
SELECT 
  prop_id, 
  product_id, 
  (CASE 
    WHEN property_id IN(1,3,5) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END)
FROM  properties;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Answer (score 1):

left outer join

```
select
    parent.name
        ,child.name
    from parent
        left outer join child on parent.familyid=child.familyid
```

will list all parents, regardless if they have children

Comment: OP's comment says it all, they didn't want a CASE statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    IF (property_id IN (1, 3, 5), 1, 0) AS matched
FROM
    properties;
```