# Counting total of matching rows without filtering them with join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following structure:

- Training Type

  - Contains multiple sessions

    - Each session can have multiple slots

      - A slot has a start date. (date column)

How to compute for each Training Type the total of sessions whose all the slots are later than today ?

What's important here is that I can't use a WHERE statement otherwise it will remove the row training 3.

I tried that but the result is wrong, it counts the total of joined rows on sessions.

I also tried the [case method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894182/matching-rows-without-filtering-sql) but I'm not sure if the method is not right, or my min(date) function is not behaving as expected

I don't really have an advanced level in SQL so I don't know what exact terms I should look for

Some data:

1. TrainingType

| id | name | required_age | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BNSSA | 18 | Sports Nautiques |
| 3 | PSE1 | 16 | Secourisme |
| 4 | PSE2 | 16 | Secourisme |
| 5 | PSC1 | 10 | Secourisme |

2. Training Sessions

| id | duration | capacity | default_location_id | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1ed73d5c-4eb8-65c8-ae00-fbb7d44c5577 | 12 | 14 | ChIJ2WHniqnTzRIR__WsniGZpIA | 2 |
| 1ed7ef8e-2f71-631a-a42b-eb7079923973 | 9 | 10 | ChIJqxJeRH8V5kcRTsGGwB0ujYA | 3 |
| 1ed7efdd-b3a5-6182-9114-e3ba8bb75fdd | 10 | 10 | ChIJuTbG23Vw5kcRHE2Nm7oV4rQ | 2 |
| 1ed7efdf-6d7d-6518-a6fd-9ba374e38b99 | 3 | 10 | ChIJKwXG2IBJrhIRUFAwL8YPQi4 | 2 |

3. Training sessions

| id | start | duration | location_id | training_session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1ed73d5c-4eb9-6284-b428-fbb7d44c5577 | 2022-12-19 14:00:00 | 3 |  | 1ed73d5c-4eb8-65c8-ae00-fbb7d44c5577 |
| 1ed73d5c-4eb9-6590-a1d4-fbb7d44c5577 | 2022-12-20 14:00:00 | 3 |  | 1ed73d5c-4eb8-65c8-ae00-fbb7d44c5577 |
| 1ed7ef8e-2f74-6830-950c-eb7079923973 | 2022-12-21 14:00:00 | 7 |  | 1ed7ef8e-2f71-631a-a42b-eb7079923973 |
| 1ed7ef8e-2f74-6ba0-b4c0-eb7079923973 | 2022-12-22 13:00:00 | 3 |  | 1ed7ef8e-2f71-631a-a42b-eb7079923973 |
| 1ed7efdd-b3a9-6034-bdbc-e3ba8bb75fdd | 2022-12-12 13:00:00 | 3 |  | 1ed7efdd-b3a5-6182-9114-e3ba8bb75fdd |
| 1ed7efdd-b3a9-63e0-bb04-e3ba8bb75fdd | 2022-12-20 12:00:00 | 3 |  | 1ed7efdd-b3a5-6182-9114-e3ba8bb75fdd |
| 1ed7efdf-6d7e-6b0c-ad5c-9ba374e38b99 | 2022-12-15 14:00:00 | 3 |  | 1ed7efdf-6d7d-6518-a6fd-9ba374e38b99 |

Expected output:

| id | name | required_age | category | sessionsCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BNSSA | 18 | Sports Nautiques | 1 |
| 3 | PSE1 | 16 | Secourisme | 1 |
| 4 | PSE2 | 16 | Secourisme | 0 |
| 5 | PSC1 | 10 | Secourisme | 0 |

Comment: Can you share a sample input table?

Comment: Sure, are screenshot enough ?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Using a subquery:

```sql
select t.id, t.name, t.required_age, t.category, (select count(*) 
    from TrainingSessions t1 where t.id = t1.type_id and not exists 
     (select 1 from Training_sessions t2 where t2.training_session_id = t1.id and t2.start <= now()))
from TrainingType t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bKF5382V).

Comment: That seems to do the trick ! Is there any way to avoid that subquery ? I was told you should avoid them as much as you can, but I guess sometimes you can't do without

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregation and left join as the following:

```
select TT.id, TT.name, TT.required_age, TT.category, count(D.type_id)
from TrainingType TT left join
(
  select T1.training_session_id, T2.type_id
  from TrainingSessionsSlots T1 join TrainingSessions T2
  on T1.training_session_id = T2.id
  group by T1.training_session_id, T2.type_id
  having min(start) > now()
) D
on TT.id = D.type_id
group by TT.id, TT.name, TT.required_age, TT.category
order by TT.id
```

`having min(start) > now()` ensures that all of the slot dates are greater than now (within training_session_id, type_id group).

`count(D.type_id)` counts only not null values, so when there is no match from the left join the `D.type_id` value will be null and the `count(D.type_id)` will be 0.

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HQjm0vyz).